# Mysql Database restore

Tags: mysql, linux, database, redhat, bugzilla

We have existing `bugzilla 3.6` running in in `Debian OS` and now I installed new `bugzilla server 4.4.4` on `REDHAT`

On Debian the MySQL version is Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.51a,

On Redhat the MySQL Version is Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.61,

I tried to import existing MySQL database to new mysql database like below

```
mysql -u bugs -p bugs < /root/backup-02-23-2015-19-00.sql
```

once import is finished.

I tried to create new bug but it giving error like below

```
Software error:
DBD::mysql::db selectcol_arrayref failed: Unknown column 'id' in 'field list' [for Statement "SELECT id FROM bug_see_also WHERE bug_id = ?"] at     Bugzilla/Bug.pm line 3497
Bugzilla::Bug::see_also('Bugzilla::Bug=HASH(0x2f794f0)') called at Bugzilla/Bug.pm line 963
Bugzilla::Bug::update('Bugzilla::Bug=HASH(0x2b00398)', '2015-02-26 11:36:43') called at /var/www/html/bugzilla/post_bug.cgi line 198
```

For help, please send mail to the webmaster (root@localhost), giving this error message and the time and date of the error.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

How did you export the database? (Show the `mysqldump` command used if possible).

Perhaps your sqldump contains only the schema, and not the data.

Comment: We are exporting like below

mysqldump -u admin --all-databases > to-file

Answer (score 0):

We are exporting like below

mysqldump -u admin --all-databases > to-file

Comment: This additional information should be added to your original question as a comment or edit. Not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps bugzilla 3.6 and 4.4.4 have significantly different db schemas, in which case a dump from one will not be compatible with the other.
Perhaps if you installed 3.6 on the new one, and loaded your database, it would work.
Then, you could upgrade from 3.6 -> 4.4.4, and hopefully the upgrader is smart enough to manipulate your db along the way.

Comment: I have followed what you said but i am getting error.

Comment: You're gonna have to provide more info than that if you want help. What was the error exactly?